# Function getResourceAsStream returns null while getResource returns a URL

Tags: java

I encountered very strange problem, I hope you will be able to help me:
I run the following line:

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(SOME_PATH);
```

And it works.
Then, I create a new class loader that points to the same file, and then

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(SOME_PATH)
```

returns null.

When I debug it, I saw that

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(SOME_PATH)
```

returns a valid URL object.

So, I debug the getResourceAsStream, and saw that it calls to getResource, and when it tries to open the steam - it fails on FileNotFoundException.

I have no idea how to solve it.
The stream is properly closed.

Anyone?

Comment: "a new classloader" <-- is it set up correctly? It just looks like it does not know of all resources known by your other classloader

Comment: Could you show some input and output...?

Comment: fge - it is set up correctly, for sure (actually, the first object and the second one are created the same). In addition, getResource returns a valid URL.

Comment: In your first code example, you say it works. You repeat it again and say it returns `null`.

Answer (score 2):

`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` will try and get the `URL` resource and do `resource.openStream()`.

It swallows any `IOException` and returns a `null` instead. If you're getting a `FileNotFoundException` that means the resource was never found in the first place.

To test this, try:

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(SOME_PATH);
if (resource != null) {
    try {
        resource.openStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you're getting any `IOException` then the `ClassLoader.getResource()` didn't find a resource or couldn't open the stream by some chance.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, but I already saw it. The getResource returns URL if it finds something, and null if not. So, it's weird that the URL is not null, and the openStream() throws FileNotFoundException. I am trying to understand why, and what work around can I do.

Comment: URL won't be null as it doesn't fetch data from the resource you specify. Also, `SOME_PATH` is a context path and not a full path.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around (pay attention to setUseCaches):

```
        InputStream zipStream = null;
        URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(SOME_PATH);
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                URLConnection urlConnection = resource.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                zipStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                NolioAction._log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
```